# Error en la conexión no se pudo encontrar el controlador

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

Hola estoy empezando con `PDO` de `PHP` y intento conectarme a la base de datos
pero me da el siguiente error:

> Error en la conexión no se pudo encontrar el controlador
> Error grave : Error no detectado: llamada a una función miembro prepare() en nulo en C:\xampp\htdocs\www.TPVJoyeriaDaira.com\Config\App\Query.php:12 Seguimiento de pila: # 0

y mi codigo el siguiente:

conexion.php

```php
class Conexion{
    private $conect;
    function __construct()
    {
        $pdo = "mysqli:host="."localhost".";dbname="."sistemadeventa";
        try {
            $this->conect = new PDO($pdo, "root", "");
            $this->conect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error en la conexion".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    function conect()
    {
        return $this->conect;    
    }
}
```

Query.php

```php
class Query extends Conexion{
    private $pdo, $con, $sql;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->pdo = new Conexion();
        $this->con = $this->pdo->conect();
    }
    function select(string $sql)
    {
        $this->sql = $sql;
        $result = $this->con->prepare($this->sql);
        $result->execute();
        $data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

usuariosModel.php

```php
class UsuariosModel extends Query{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function getUsuario()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
        $data = $this->select($sql);
        return $data;
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Y la consulta SQL?

Comment: Si quieres lo puedo añadir

Comment: La e hecho en otro archivo

Comment: Pero si la conexión funcionaria debería ejecutar el sql pero me el error antes